# How do I copy a Request object with a different URL?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm writing a wrapper around `fetch` that I would like to add something to the URL before making the request e.g. identifying query parameters. I can't figure out how to make a copy of a given a `Request` object with a different URL than the original. My code looks like:

```
// My function which tries to modify the URL of the request
function addLangParameter(request) {
    const newUrl = request.url + "?lang=" + lang;
    return new Request(newUrl, /* not sure what to put here */);
}

// My fetch wrapper
function myFetch(input, init) {
    // Normalize the input into a Request object
    return Promise.resolve(new Request(input, init))
        // Call my modifier function
        .then(addLangParameter)
        // Make the actual request
        .then(request => fetch(request));
}
```

I tried putting the original request as the second arguent to the `Request` constructor, like so:

```
function addLangParameter(request) {
    const newUrl = request.url + "?lang=" + lang;
    return new Request(newUrl, request);
}
```

which seems to copy most of the attributes of the old request but doesn't seem to preserve the `body` of the old request. For example,

```
const request1 = new Request("/", { method: "POST", body: "test" });
const request2 = new Request("/new", request1);
request2.text().then(body => console.log(body));
```

I would expect to log "test", but instead it logs the empty string, because the body is not copied over.

Do I need to do something more explicit to copy all of the attributes correctly, or is there a nice shortcut that will do something reasonable for me?

I'm using the [github/fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch) polyfill, but have tested with both the polyfill and the native `fetch` implementation in the lastest Chrome.

Comment: Don't show pseudo code: show real code.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I added the actual code. I think it makes it harder to understand the actual problem, maybe it'll be helpful.

Comment: rather than harder, your new code actually makes it obvious what you're asking about, by showing your use of the Request object in the code itself.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like your best bet is to read the body using the `Body` interface that Requests implement:

https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#body

This can only be done asynchronously since the underlying "consume body" operation always reads asynchronously and returns a promise. Something like this should work:

```
const request = new Request('/old', { method: 'GET' });
const bodyP = request.headers.get('Content-Type') ? request.blob() : Promise.resolve(undefined);
const newRequestP =
  bodyP.then((body) =>
    new Request('/new', {
      method: request.method,
      headers: request.headers,
      body: body,
      referrer: request.referrer,
      referrerPolicy: request.referrerPolicy,
      mode: request.mode,
      credentials: request.credentials,
      cache: request.cache,
      redirect: request.redirect,
      integrity: request.integrity,
    })
  );
```

After doing that, `newRequestP` will be a promise that resolves to the request you want. Luckily, fetch is asynchronous anyway so your wrapper shouldn't be significantly hampered by this.

(Note: Reading the body using `.blob()` off of a request that does not have a body seems to return a zero-length Blob object, but it's incorrect to specify any body, even a zero-length one, on a GET or HEAD request. I believe that checking if the original request had `Content-Type` set is an accurate proxy for whether it has a body, which is what we really need to determine.)

Comment: Looks like this doesn't currently work in the github/fetch polyfill (which doesn't appropriately set the `Content-Type` header), but this works great in Chrome. Thanks!

Comment: A correct `body` assignment [following MDN†](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request) might be `const body = ['GET', 'HEAD'].includes(r.method) ? undefined : await r.blob()`.  † MDN states:  "a request using the GET or HEAD method cannot have a body."