# Changing the URL of a Request object from the Fetch API

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Say if I have small function that takes a `Request` object as an argument, and calls the `fetch()` API.

Except I always want to append something to the url, such as `?foo=bar`. I'm curious what the best way would be to go about that.

Example:

```
function fetchFoo(request) {

   request.url += '?foo=bar';
   return fetch(request);

}
```

The issue I have is that this won't work. The [Fetch API specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/url) states that the url property read-only.

Is there a way to work around this? I'm thinking I might need to construct an all-new `Request` object, but I'm unsure what a clever way is to inherit all the options from the previous `Request` object.

Note that I am able to override any other property by using this syntax:

```
var originalRequest = new Request('/url');
var overriddenRequest = new Request(originalRequest, { method: 'POST' });
```

Although it wasn't clear from the docs, it seems that the second init parameter takes precedence over the values passed via the `originalRequest` parameter. I just can't seem to come up with a way to do this for the url as well.

Comment: rather than passing a request object, pass the request options (probably a big rewrite though, right?)

Comment: @JaromandaX ideally my library can accept every argument that plain `fetch()` can also accept and just 'decorate' the request. Supporting a subset of arguments might be a good plan B though, thanks!

Comment: another alternative is a `requestFoo` function, that takes arguments just like `new Request` and add the `?foo=bar` at that point

Comment: @JaromandaX it's a good idea, except there's an edge case! The `new Request` constructor can also take another `Request` object as its first parameter. I added some notes to my question about that just now.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but that shouldn't be a problem using the `requestFoo` function I suggested, as you'll know in your code if the argument is a Request object or a string - I thought there may be a simple way to create a new Request based on the passed in request, but you can't "retrieve" `body`, `redirect` or `integrity` properties from a Request object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy a Request object with a different URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34640286/how-do-i-copy-a-request-object-with-a-different-url)

Answer (score 3):

You could leverage the keys that are on the `Request.prototype` to build a new `Request` object in just a few lines.

```
function newRequest(input, init) {
    var url = input;
    if (input instanceof Request) {
        url = mutateUrl(input.url);

        init = init || {};
        Object.keys(Request.prototype).forEach(function (value) {
            init[value] = input[value];
        });
        delete init.url;

        return input.blob().then(function (blob) {
            if (input.method.toUpperCase() !== 'HEAD' && input.method.toUpperCase() !== 'GET' && blob.size > 0) {
                init.body = blob;
            }

            return new Request(url, init);
        })
    } else {
        url = mutateUrl(url);
    }

    return new Request(url, init);
}
```

Note the special case for `body` discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34641566/271351).